# Dynamic style on RML documents

Tags: odoo, openerp-7, rml

What I need is to have every second row of a table to have a different background colour. I have successfully created my method that can be called from the rml document and returns the hex colour. What I need is a way on rml side to set the background-colour attribute of the `tr` tag to the return value of my method. How can this be done ? I have been using the official [documentation](https://www.reportlab.com/docs/rml2pdf-userguide.pdf) and looking specifically at the chapter 11 Conditional formatting but I do not see anything. Essentially what I want to do it the following:

```
<tr style="background-colour: [[_get_colour(index)]];" />
```

`_get_colour` will return a string that will contain the hex value of a colour

**Edit:** As it turns out the docIf RML tags that are used for conditional formatting are not implemented in openerp v7 according to [this](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/reportlab-conditional-table-header-15143) and I have to resort to a different solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an example of that problem being solved in an rml in the system. I ended up resolving the issue with the following:

```
<tr>[[ setTag('tr','tr',{'style': 'Move_Line_Contect_Assign_State_background' if picking.move_lines.index(move_lines) % 2 else 'Move_Line_Contect_Assign_State'}) ]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't test this at the moment, but here's an idea that might work:

Make two `<tr>` for each iteration (1 for each style). In one of them, check if the index is even or `removeParentNode('tr')`, in the other, check if the index is odd or `removeParentNode('tr')`. This way only one or the other table row will display on each iteration, but not both.

Example (untested):

```
<tr style="style1">[[ (index%2 == 0 and display.content) or removeParentNode('tr')]]</tr>
<tr style="style2">[[ (index%2 != 0 and display.content) or removeParentNode('tr')]]</tr>
```

Comment: That sounded like a great solution but the `index` variable is not defined so it is not working for me, but I might use your approach since its cleaner to define somehow the index variable

Comment: Sorry, I assumed that you already have found a way to get the `index`, as you used it in the question example.